# How do i echo success when inputting data is successful

Tags: php

How do i echo Success Message when the data is successfully inserted in database.

**My error code in html**

```
<p><?php echo display_error(); ?></p>
```

**Funtion of Display Error**

```
function display_error() {
    global $errors;

    if (count($errors) > 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible show fade">
                      <div class="alert-body">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                          <span>&times;</span>
                        </button><b><center>';
            foreach ($errors as $error){
                echo $error .'</b></center></div></div>';
            }
    }
}
```

**Code if data we're successfully inserted**

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);

        if (isset($_POST['user_type'])) {
            $user_type = e($_POST['user_type']);
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, user_type, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', '$user_type', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            header('location: home.php'); // I just made this just to know if the data were successfully inserted to my database
        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, user_type, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', 'user', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Just check the return value of `mysqli_query`.  If it's `false`, there was an error and you should use `mysqli_error` to find out what it is.  If it's not `false`, the query was successful and you can output whatever you like.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the tips. Do you have any tutorial that can make my website more secure?

Comment: Hi, No, we are not supposed to recommend tutorials among other things on SO. But a google on a few obvious keywords should get you started

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns `TRUE` on success of `INSERT`

> Return Values
>
> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So, definitely, if your `INSERT` works, if will return `TRUE`.

Please add an if condition:

```
if (mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
 // .. Add code for printing success message.
}
```

Comment: where should i add if condition?

Comment: and also what will be the code for echoing the success message i'm just new when it comes to PHP :D

Comment: You can add the if condition as stated in the answer wherever you are doing database insert.

Comment: can you make an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// this is simplest way i am suggesting you .

$row=mysqli_query($db_connection,$your_query);
if($row)
{
$info['msg']='sucess';
}
// now call this variable in any div where you would like to show sucess message ,
?>
```

Comment: HI Farhan and welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead creating multiple answers, write one answer and show the different options the question author would have. It is also good practice to stick to the variable names the question author uses to avoid misunderstanding. Thanks for being part of our community!

Answer (score 0):

OR you can use this code .

```
if(mysqli_query($DBconnection,$query))
  {
    echo '
       <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>Registration Complete</h3>
        </div>
       </div>';


}
```

Comment: "Contact me off-site" isn't how SO works. Please keep any answers on-site, without things like that.

Comment: Also, images of code isn't allowed in questions or answers.

Comment: then why you guys has enable that function?

Comment: I said images **of code**. There's no "no images what so ever or you're banned", but using images to post code isn't allowed. You can post results of code, or use it to supplement your post, but it cannot replace some specific components. Additionally, filtering the "bad" images from the allowed ones is considerably more complicated than you might think. That's more a [question for the devs](//meta.stackexchange.com) though.